# How to combine matrixes with different time vectors in MATLAB in a fast way

Tags: matlab, loops, time

I have two instruments which measure the same component, but in different time intervals. One is 1 h the other one is 5 min. To do an inter-comparison I thought I average the 5 min intervals to 1 h. However with data gaps of the instrument with 5 min resolution this averaging is not straight forward. I tried the following code which loops over the time and makes some averages which takes quite some time and doesn't always work. Is there a better solution to that?

```
time_d is the time vector of the instrument with 5 min resolution
d2 is my data with 3 columns; 

time_d=t5;
time_ave = datenum(2015,10,1,1,0,0) : 1/24 : datenum(2015,10,20,23,0,0);
 d_ave = [time_ave' NaN(length(time_ave),3)];
   for k = 1 : length(time_ave)
    if mod(k,24) == 1
    disp(datestr(time_ave(k),'dd-mmm-yyyy'))
   end

findex = find( time_d-0.5/24<=time_ave(k)&time_ave(k)<time_d+0.5/24 );
if ~isempty(findex)
    d_ave(k,2:end) = nanmean(d2(findex,2:end),1);


end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `interp1`?  You can use the time vector from the larger data set (5 min) and expand the 1 hour set to match.  Mathworks added the `next` and `previous` options recently to hold a particular value.

Another option is to use the `filter` function to make a moving average.  I believe Mathworks even shows an example in `doc filter`.